# Griffiths problem 5.10

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the force on the triangular loop:
>
> [image]

For the piece $CA$ it is easy beacuse the magnetic field is constant. We have that $$F_{\text{CA}}=\frac{\mu_0Ia}{2\pi s}\hat{y}=\frac{\mu_0Ia}{2\pi s}\langle 0,1,0\rangle.$$

For the piece $AB$, I did the following: At a distance $l$ from the point $A$ we consider an element $dl$ and ask ourselves what is the elemental force $dF$ on it. I think that it should be $$dF = I(dl\times B)=I\cdot dl\cdot \frac{\mu_0 I }{4\pi(s+y)}$$ where $y$ is the perpendicular distance from the line $AC$ to the element $dl$. We can now integrate from $0$ to $a$ and use the fact that $\frac{y}{l}=\sin(\pi/3)$ to get that $$F_{\text{AB}} = \frac{\mu_0I^2}{2\sqrt{3}\pi}\ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2s}\right).$$

Now I am confused about the direction of this force $F.$ According to me the force is perpendicular (inward) to the line $AB$ and thus $$F_{\text{AB}}=\frac{\mu_0I^2}{2\sqrt{3}\pi}\ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2s}\right)\langle \sqrt{3}/2,-1/2,0\rangle.$$

Similarly $$F_{\text{BC}}=\frac{\mu_0I^2}{2\sqrt{3}\pi}\ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2s}\right)\langle -\sqrt{3}/2,-1/2,0\rangle.$$ On adding these force up I do not get the correct answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: PhysicsPages.com is the site you need to use.  http://physicspages.com/pdf/Griffiths%20EM/Griffiths%20Problems%2005.10.pdf

Comment: Please read carefully the site [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a small mistake, it should be $$\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi(s+y)}$$ instead of $$\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi(s+y)}.$$ Then everything works out.